# Why do I not see a transaction after 3 days?

Tags: transactions

I bought 11 BTC from someone and to prove they sent I had them take a s/s of the transaction.
It has now been 3 days and I do not even see it in unconfirmed part of my wallet. Is there some way to cancel payments? Did he somehow scam me? We both use bitcoin wallet qt. Any help will be much appreciated.

I forgot to say that I reset the blockchain already and asked him to do so. (whether or not he did I do not know)

Thanks again

Comment: If you have the transaction id you can look it up on http://blockexplorer.com and verify that the correct number of coins were sent to the address you gave the seller.

Comment: Where do I find the transaction ID? I looked up his address and mine already and it shows 0.00 being sent or received. But I saw the s/s and it looked like everything was right

Comment: Resetting your block chain will make it take much longer for the transaction to show up. Look up your account in blockexplorer or a similar site. If the transaction shows up, you're good. If not, you weren't paid.

Comment: I looked up my address he "sent it" too

Comment: It didnt show up with anything...

Comment: I keep hitting enter... So I guess I got scammed then... It looked like he sent it though